# WAMP 2.5 (Apache 2.4.9) enable access from all computer on LAN

Tags: apache, wampserver

I built 2 websites locally using WAMP and I would like to make it accessible to anyone in or local network.

I set up 2 virtual hosts with the following configuration in my **httpd-vhosts.conf**:

```
#Vistage
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/vistagebusinessexpo.com"
    ServerName vistagebusinessexpo.local
    ServerAlias www.vistagebusinessexpo.local
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
    <Directory  "C:/wamp/www/vistagebusinessexpo.com">
        AllowOverride All
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

#CaterCon
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/catercon.com"
    ServerName catercon.local
    ServerAlias www.catercon.local
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
    <Directory  "C:/wamp/www/catercon.com">
        AllowOverride All
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/8 localhost ::1 10.1.1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My **Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts** file is configured as follow:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       vistagebusinessexpo.local
::1             vistagebusinessexpo.local
127.0.0.1       catercon.local
::1             catercon.local
```

The problem is that each time I am try to connect from any other computer in our network I get "Error 403 Access Denied/Forbidden"

So far I tried multiple suggestions:

- Click the "Put Online" button and try Accessing the website with IPAdress/website.local
- Modifying the **httpd.conf** file to allow access to all the IP on our local network
- Modifying the **httpd.conf** file to "allow from allow"

Right now I am running out of solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok,

**Point 1:** As soon as you configure your own Virtual Hosts the use of the `Put Online and Put Offline` menus becomes irrelevant, as Apache will ignore the localhost configured in the `httpd.conf` file, which is the only thing amended by using those menus.

**Point 2:** You should really configure `localhost` as a Virtual Host as well as your other sites. It should be the first VH in the definition file so making it the default site, if someone uses the ip address of your server they will then get a Access Not Allowed as long as you leave it configured as `Require local` only.

**Point 3:** For some reason you are using Apache 2.2 access syntax in one VH and 2.4 in the other. As you are using Apache 2.4, stick with the 2.4 syntax. The 2.2 syntax does work if you have `mod_access_compat.so` activated in Apache, **but why bother**!

**Point5:** Each of your VHOST's is now configurable seperately, but must be done manually ( edit and restart Apache )

So can I suggest you try this as your `httpd-vhosts.conf` file

```
#localhost
# Always have this as the first VHOST
# Never have access set to anything other than 'require local'
# The any access using ip address of your server will get sent here
## and get a Not Allowed Error
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

#Vistage
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/vistagebusinessexpo.com"
    ServerName vistagebusinessexpo.local
    ServerAlias www.vistagebusinessexpo.local
    ErrorLog "logs/vistagebusinessexpo-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/vistagebusinessexpo-access.log" common
    <Directory  "C:/wamp/www/vistagebusinessexpo.com">
        AllowOverride All
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Require local
        Require ip 10.1.1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

#CaterCon
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/catercon.com"
    ServerName catercon.local
    ServerAlias www.catercon.local
    ErrorLog "logs/catercon-error.log
    CustomLog "logs/catercon-access.log" common
    <Directory  "C:/wamp/www/catercon.com">
        AllowOverride All
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Require local
        Require ip 10.1.1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I corrected the different errors in my **httpd-vhosts.conf**. Now when I type localhost/ I get the wamp homepage. Which is great. Thanks for that.

However, I still cannot access the website from other computers. I do not even get a 403 forbidden anymore. I get a message saying "This page can't be displayed"

Comment: I checked with my IT department and we do have a DNS Server

Comment: well you will have get the IT guys to register these two sites so that each other PC can use the domain name you have assigned to each site. Then Apache will know where to go when they use the domain name in their browsers

Comment: Thank you very much RiggsFolly! That was super helpful and really specific.

Answer (score 1):

I did this and it works!
I know it is not a good habbit to create virtualhost in the httpd.conf, but after a lot of headaches it worked and also PCs in the same network can access to my website:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www
<Directory  "c:/wamp/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This is for the localhost.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/mysite/"
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    ServerName mysite.com
    <Directory "c:/wamp/www/mysite/">
            AllowOverride All
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted     
    </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

And this for the site. Very similar to RiggsFolly answer.

Also in the same file modify the `<Directory />` to:

```
<Directory />
AllowOverride All
Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Lastly in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host, add `127.0.0.1   mysite.com` .

For others PCs can access to your website just add in their host file:

```
your-ip    mysite.com
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

In apache 2.4 changes all the Require local by Require all granted for the files:

```
C:/-> wamp64 -> bin -> apache 2.4.X -> config -> httpd.conf
C:/-> wamp64 -> bin -> apache 2.4.X -> config -> extra -> httpd-vhost.conf
```